# Cumulative returns when shorting with regards to variance drag

Tags: time-series, asset-returns

What is the convention when calculating/analyzing daily returns for a strategy when shorting is involved? I found the following answer regarding variance drag useful in understanding why there is a difference in long vs short cumulative returns: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/47035/69488

However, I was not sure what the next steps were when analyzing daily returns of short positions when the return is negative.

The following is a simple example to illustrate what I am having an issue understanding (screenshot relevant):

**Strategy**: some signal is generated on a single futures contract to go long or short a single unit of it.
So in this example, the future is shorted at \$100, and 2 days later, the position was closed (bought back) at \$121. I understand the trade return to be -21%. However, when you calculate the return over the 2 days using cumulative returns, the overall return is -19%.

I have a long time series of the daily return going long or short, and a column for cumulative returns of the strategy. I noticed this difference (due to variance drag) as I was analyzing stats on a per trade level (what is the average return per trade, per long, per short, etc.) -> I had a timeseries dataframe of daily returns and also a dataframe where each row was every trade: the cumulative return on the daily returns and on each trade were different.

So **what is the convention if I want to simply analyse series of daily returns which involve short positions? Is it not possible to accurately do so without specifying portfolio size or leverage?**

I apologize for my long-winded explanation and what Im guessing is a super basic concept that I am missing. If relevant as a guide for my math/stat level, I am a college freshman studying CS.

Thank you.

[image]